# Android: startActivity(intent) for fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am dealing with fragment class and a broadcastReceiver class. the problem is, i need to pass a value from broadcastreceiver class to the fragment class and start the fragment class (startActivity(intent) if i use activities class). i tried many ways from Google but the program crashes. is there any way to do this?

i can't change the fragment to fragmentActivity/others because other classes are effected.
i can't make the broadcastReceiver class to fragment also.

this is the broadcastreceiver class:

```
Fragmented fragment = new Fragmented();
  Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
            bundle2.putString("key", key);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle2);

        fragment.onStart();
```

and this is the fragment class:

```
@Override
    public void onStart()
    {

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
              String hello = bundle.getString("key");
              System.out.println(hello);

            super.onStart();

            FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"xxxx");
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(getActivity());
        EasyTracker.getTracker().sendView("(2.0)New_MainView");

    }
```

and the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.XX.XX.Receiver: java.lang.NullPointerException 10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1809)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117) 10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)10-20 
13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at com.XX.XX.Fragmented.onStart(Fragmented.java:265)10-20 

 13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):     at com.xx.xx.Receiver.onReceive(Receiver.java:84)10-20 

13:20:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(16572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1798)
```

Comment: You are in urgent need of reading up on Fragments and Activities! Fragments can't be used independently. They must be a part of Activity layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this method inside your receiver class. And call this method to notify the activity.

```
public static final String YOUR_KEY = "yourbackagename.YOUR_KEY";
void broadcastMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_KEY);
    intent.putString("Key", message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Inside your activity create the BroadcastReceiver and listen for the broadcast. This activity should be your main activity which is supposed to hold the fragment.

```
registerReceiver(reciever, new IntentFilter(YourReciever.YOUR_KEY));

final BroadcastReceiver reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)
         * @since Oct 7, 2013
         * @author rajeshcp
         */
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try{
                Fragmented fragment = new Fragmented();
                            fragment.setArguments(intent.getExtras());
                            FragmentTransaction trasaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            //R.id.fragment_content The id given to the FrameLayout in your main lay out fro the Activity
                            trasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() + "");
                    trasaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    trasaction.commit();
            }catch(Exception exception){
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Error on recieve of notification");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: hy, thanks for the answer. i was trying to do as you suggested since yesterday but the whole thing works except the fragmented class does not open. and i'm pretty sure the program does not even enter receiver method. any idea why?

Comment: its ok. thank you so much. just added the method at the wrong place. but now its settled. thank you..

Comment: and if you don't mind, do you know how to off the notification after the transaction has been executed? currently because of the notification which is still active after back button been pressed after the transaction succeed, each time i click on the fragmented class, the notification effects the class.any idea?

Comment: after the execution you can stop listening to the broadcast receiver using this function unregisterReceiver(reciever);

Comment: hy, thank you for the reply but it does not work. I tried putting it onResume(),onPause() even onDestroy(). but its still there. any other option?